# How to deal with unity build setting wrong

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
The Assembly Google.Protobuf is referenced by MySql.Data ('Assets/Plugins/MySql.Data.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <f7b72beb77a34ddcb6dd85f95c6547e1>:0)
```

I can connect the mysql, I have been dealing with this all day and can't find a solution.Really ridiculous, Can you help me solve the problem? Thank you for your help.

mysql.data 8.0.33.1 , unity 2022.1.9f1c1 , I have changed the mysql.data's version , but failed. too high or other something?